# How to get rendered colored text in GitLab / GitHub using AsciiDoc?

Tags: github, colors, gitlab, asciidoc

I'm new to AsciiDoc, so I made a simple project on GitHub to test the rendering of colored text.

The project is located at https://github.com/youngjim01/asciidoc-test

I can't seem to get the colored text to show when using the examples found on https://asciidoc-py.github.io/

Here's the source that I'm using to test:

```
[red]#Obvious# and [big red yellow-background]*very obvious*.

[underline]#Underline text#, [overline]#overline text# and
[blue line-through]*bold blue and line-through*.
```

It was taken directly from https://asciidoc-py.github.io/asciidoc.css-embedded.html

Any help in understand what I'm doing wrong is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks goes to mojavelinux for answering this question in the thread at https://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Color-for-Text-td7509.html#a8689

To recap the most important point:

> GitHub and GitLab do not permit using colors in content in the repository preview view. This has been requested countless times, and the response is always to reject that request.